# Is the return of last_insert_id always correct?

Tags: c++, mysql, mariadb

If I have the 2 following functions:

```
int AccessDb::InsertColValue(string tableName, string col, string val)
{
    try
    {
        sql::Statement *stmt;
        bool ret;

        if ((nomTable != "") && (col != "") && (val != ""))
        {
            string query = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + "(" + col + ") values (";
                    query += val + ");";

            stmt = con->createStatement();
            ret = stmt->execute(query);
        }

        delete stmt;

        return 0;
    }
    catch (sql::SQLException &e)
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

and

```
long AccessDb::LastInsertId()
{
    try
    {
        sql::Statement *stmt;
        sql::ResultSet *res;

        string query = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS LAST_ID";

        stmt = con->createStatement();
        res = stmt->executeQuery(query);

        delete stmt;

        long lastId;
        while (res->next())
        {
            lastId = res->getInt("LAST_ID");
        }

        return lastId;
    }
    catch (sql::SQLException &e)
    {
      return -1;
    }
}
```

Can I be sure that the return of LastInsertId() will always give me the correct id if I write the following lines and if the id is auto generated by the database?

```
AccessDb adb; // initialize the connexion with the db
int ret = adb.InsertColValue("people", "name", "John");
if (ret == 0)
    long lastId = adb.LastInsertId();
```

If the previous code is called somewhere else at the same time, can I have a wrong value in my lastId variable ? If yes, do I have to use locks and unlocks on my table to avoid that or another solution ?

Comment: The function is session-specific, so as long as only one process can be associated with a given session, it will return the last insert id for that session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what the docs says:

> The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a
>   per-connection basis. This means that the value returned by the
>   function to a given client is the first AUTO_INCREMENT value generated
>   for most recent statement affecting an AUTO_INCREMENT column by that
>   client. This value cannot be affected by other clients, even if they
>   generate AUTO_INCREMENT values of their own. This behavior ensures
>   that each client can retrieve its own ID without concern for the
>   activity of other clients, and without the need for locks or
>   transactions.

So, unless your own code on the client is sharing a connection between several threads (Which it looks like you're not, since there are no mutexes or locks in your code) you can be sure SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() isn't mixed up with any other connection or client.

I can't find the docs for the C++ mysql library but verify what the return value of `ret = stmt->execute(query);` in your `InsertColValue()` function means, such that you're sure the only possible way that you fail to insert anything is when an exception is thrown.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm using several threads but I tried to reduce my example to the most simple and forgot to say it. Should I use mutexes to be sure that the last id is correct ?

Comment: @Aleph0 I don't know if you need to or not, it depends on how you've architected the code. What you need to ensure is that no other SQL is run on the same connection inbetween the INSERT statement and the point where you fetch the LAST_INSERT_ID()

Comment: @nos Thank you, I'll try to see where I have to put critical sections.